# Rails how to push data from one rails application to other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap

I am creating a job website where candidate fill his information and admin/team member can modify these detail and after modification i want to send this data to some other application   where it get saves .notice that i want to push each single record like in every candidate information page there will be a button for "push to other application"

I am thinking to do this by creating soap services and sending data through soap api,so please help me by assisting how can i create soap api in rails and send data tho other application.

And please assist me the other ways how can i do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a step back and consider why your doing this. Separating the model form and model save into two applications seems unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to other application database and insert the records. The other application can read the records from its database. It is easier to use database communication than soap.

Answer (score 0):

You should not even think about creating a SOAP service, there are no any good implementations of it in Ruby.

Consider using REST API and ActiveResource instead.

- [ActiveResource GitHub page](https://github.com/rails/activeresource)
- [ActiveResource 3.2.17 Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html)

There are RailsCasts about ActiveResource, though they are a bit outdated you'll get the idea.

- [#94 ActiveResource Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics)
- [#95 More on ActiveResource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource)

However if for some reason you decide to create a SOAP service take a look at [WashOut](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) and [Savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) gems.